# Ambiguous conversion to reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ambiguous

Why is the conversion of `CL` instance to `const int&` ambiguous here?

```
struct CL
{
    operator const int&()
    {
    }
    operator int&()
    {
    }
};

void fnc(const int&)
{
}

int main()
{
    CL cl;
    fnc(cl);
}
```

There are two ways:
1). `cl.operator const int&()` leads to user-defined conversion
2). `cl.operator int&()` leads to user-defined conversion and then qualification conversion (`int&` to `const int&`)

First way is better than second way, isn't it? I saw Standard, but found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because both conversions are applicable (equally good) in this context. That is, both `int&` and `const int&` can be bound by `const int&`.

The conversion would not be ambiguous, if you had:

```
void fnc(int&)
{
}
```